# how to calculate multivariable integral?

Tags: integration

Let's say we want to find the work of a force on a particle. The particle moves in a x(t) trajectory. The force changes like F(T) where T is the temperature. How can I find the integral of Fds?

Comment: The temperature will probably depend on the position. If not, the force is constant and thus comes out of the integral, and you only have the length of the trajectory taken times the force.

Comment: no temperature is not depended on time

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate $\int_CF\,\mathrm{d}s$, where $C$ is the trajectory traced out by the particle. As mentioned by User001, if you want to get out a number, you have to actually **have** a curve, which will define the bounds for the integral. You say that the particle "moves in a $x(t)$ trajectory". This sentence doesn't make much sense, but what can be made from this is that the particle moves in one dimension, and that its trajectory is parametrized by $t$, so there is a curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that the position of the particle is given by $\gamma(t)=x(t)$ for all $t\in[a,b]$, where $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ is some interval. For example, let's say the particle went from $a\in\mathbb{R}$ to $b\in\mathbb{R}$ in a straight line, where $a<b$, then a parametrisation is $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $\gamma(t)=t$. Of course in general, the path traced out will not be so trivial (although in one dimension the options are really quite limited).

You say that the force depends on the temperature. Now there are two options: either the temperature does depend on $x$, or it does not.

If it does not depend on $x$, which means that in your whole space the temperature is constant, then your force is constant everywhere, and thus $\int_CF\,\mathrm{d}s=F\int_C\,\mathrm{d}s=F\cdot L$, where $L$ is the length of the trajectory traced out by the particele and $F$ is the value of the force (which is, as mentioned, a constant).

If it does depend on the $x$, so $T=T(x)$ (note that $T$ does not depend on $t$) and $F(T)=F(T(x))$, then $\int_CF(T(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$ is not trivial. We can simply write $F=F(x)$, to ease the notation. To calculate this integral, we note that
\begin{align}
\int_CF(x)\,\mathrm{d}s=\int_a^bF(x(t))\cdot|x'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t,
\end{align}
which is of course just a simply application of the substitution rule, essentially meaning that you have to take into account the speed with which you trace out the trajectory. Note also that this works if we are in more than one dimension, but then
\begin{align}
\int_C\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=\int_a^b\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot\mathbf{r}'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.
\end{align}
To address your comment about the temperature not depending on time, this is true as stated, simply because there **is no time dependence in the problem as stated**. However as soon as we want to calculate the integral (and in one dimension you don't even have to parametrize, but in more than one you usually do) you have to parametrize the trajectory over which you are integrating, and there comes this "time dependence". This is of course not really a time dependence but because $t$ is **just a parameter which we use to describe the curve, and we could have equally well chosen, say $\zeta$**.  It of course does not change anything. But the integral **must** depend on this new parameter, because well, we formulated the trajectory in terms of it, and our function depends on the trajectory! We have transferred our problem from an integral over a curve (which might be complicated) to an integral over an interval (which is simple), and had to account for this by a property of the way of translating (i.e. the parametrization), namely the derivative.

It is intuitive to think about this parameter as a sort of time and as the derivative of the parametrisation as the speed with which the curve is being traced out, as is of course done in phyiscs.